# (WinUI) DatePicker SelectedDate Binding null issue (x:Bind and Binding are different results)

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, winui-3, winui

(WInUI3)
DatePicker SelectedDate x:Bind and Binding are different results ??
x:Bind => SelectedDate is null
Binding => SelectedDate is 1923-1-1

Result Image :

[image: result-screenshoot]

How to do let binding is also null ?

Code :

```xaml
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Bind vm.MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<StackPanel DataContext="{x:Bind vm}">
   <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```csharp
public class MyTable : ObservableObject
{
    private DateTimeOffset? _mydate;
    public DateTimeOffset? MyDate
    {
        get => _mydate;
        set => SetProperty(ref _mydate, value);
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyTable vm = new MyTable();
    public MainWindow() { this.InitializeComponent(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `Binding` doesn't pass the `null` value and converts it to some default value. This might be because `DateTimeOffset` is a `struct`.

Anyhow, here's a workaround creating a custom control:

```cs
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public CustomDatePicker()
    {
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, OnSelectedDatePropertyChanged);
    }

    private void OnSelectedDatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        if (this.SelectedDate <= this.MinYear)
        {
            this.SelectedDate = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It works with both `Binding` and `x:Bind`:

```xml
<local:CustomDatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<StackPanel DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel}">
    <local:CustomDatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?